# Find all subsequences within double squared brackets

Tags: java, regex

My input text looks like this:

`..some_text0 [[some_text1]] some_text2 [[some_text3]] some_text4 ....`

I want to extract all texts contained within double squared brackets, or I want to obtain separately the groups:

```
some_text1
some_text3
```

I tried this solution:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[.*\\]\\]").matcher(line_input);

while (m.find()) {

  System.out.println("Found: " + matcher.group());

}
```

but this prints me:

```
[[some_text1]] some_text2 [[some_text3]]
```

as only result. How to achieve my goal?

Comment: The group match nothing.

Comment: @PranavCBalan your solution works, if you provide me an explanation as answer aerea I will mark your answer

Comment: @Leonardo: Do not use `"\\[\\[.*?\\]\\]"`, it is an inefficient regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex for this task is as below

```
\[\[(.*?)]]
```

It searches for the `[[` follow by any string that closes with `]]`

Here is [DEMO](http://ideone.com/LwN2w1) and [explanation](https://regex101.com/r/pD9iC0/3)

Comment: Note that you do not need to escape `]` outside character classes. Also, this regex `\[\[([^\]]+)\]\]` won't match `[[text=[placeholder]_test]]`, [mine will](https://regex101.com/r/pG1nZ4/5) as it basically works like `.*?`.

Comment: It was outside the scope what the OP wanted, but it is included after small correction.

Answer (score 1):

Using `\[\[.*?]]` regex that is just slow and `.` does not match a newline by default, you might confront an issue when backtracking limit is exhausted if you parse very long strings.

I suggest using a regex based on the unrolling-the-loop method:

```
\[{2}([^\]]*(?:\](?!\])[^\]]*)*)\]{2}
```

Or even a shorter

```
\[{2}([^\]]*(?:\][^\]]+)*)\]{2}
```

See [regex demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/pG1nZ4/3) and [demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/pG1nZ4/4).

Here is a [Java demo](http://ideone.com/NJ4jsa):

```
String str = "some_text0 [[some_text1]] some_text2 [[some_text3]] some_text4";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("\\[{2}([^\\]]*(?:\\][^\\]]+)*)\\]{2}");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Result:

```
some_text1
some_text3
```

Regex breakdown:

- `\[{2}` - match exactly 2 `[` symbols
- `[^\]]*` - match 0 or more symbols other than `]`
- `(?:\][^\]]+)*` - match 0 or more sequences of...

  - `\]` - a single `]` that is followed by
  - `[^\]]+` - 1 or more symbols other than `]`
- `\]{2}` - match exactly 2 `]` symbols.

The difference from `.*?`-based regex is that matching becomes more linear and thus the regex pattern is much faster and less error prone.

Comment: Your regex also matches empty brackets like `[[]]`

Comment: Yes, it is inline with `"\\[\\[.*\\]\\]"` and `"\\[\\[.*?\\]\\]"` that works for OP.

Comment: @MaxZoom: Not a problem, use Group 1.

Comment: He wants the text inside the brackets, not brackets alone.